# How make list of dict from list of keys and values from list of lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, dimension

I have two lists:
first is list of keys,
second is list of values having list.
I want to make list of dictionaries, but I don't know to do that.

```
keys=['number','type']
values=[[1,2,3,4],['bool','int','float','double']]
```

I am trying make something, but i am in death point with this.

```
j=0
for k in keys:
    i=0
    for v in values[j]:
        a=keys[j]
        a=a+':'
        a=a+str(values[j][i])
        print(a)
        i=i+1
    j=j+1
```

I want to have output like this:

```
list=[
    {'number':1,'type':'bool'},
    {'number':2,'type':'int'},
    {'number':3,'type':'float'},
    {'number':4,'type':'double'}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
keys=['number','type']
values=[[1,2,3,4],['bool','int','float','double']]

newList = []
for i in range(len(values[0])):
    tmp = {}
    for j, key in enumerate(keys):
        tmp[key] = values[j][i]

    newList.append(tmp)

print(newList)
```

Output:

```
[{'number': 1, 'type': 'bool'}, {'number': 2, 'type': 'int'}, {'number': 3, 'type': 'float'}, {'number': 4, 'type': 'double'}]
```

tip for future: you can use `enumerate(list)` instead of using `i = i+1` or `i += 1`

Comment: @roubert no problem! I'd be happy if you could mark my answer as correct

Answer (score 1):

Using `list comprehension`, `zip()` and `dict()`. `zip(*values)` will yield pairs `item` from the two sub-lists in `values`. `dict(zip(keys, item))` will produce each `dict` in the list from tuples, produced by `zip(keys, item)`

```
keys=['number','type']
values=[[1,2,3,4],['bool','int','float','double']]

spam = [dict(zip(keys, item)) for item in zip(*values)]
print(spam)
```

output

```
[{'number': 1, 'type': 'bool'}, {'number': 2, 'type': 'int'}, 
 {'number': 3, 'type': 'float'}, {'number': 4, 'type': 'double'}]
```

Comment: Nice! Could you add a short explanation to say how this works? Just a sentence or two is fine. Links to documentation might help as well. Or I could add an explanation for you, if you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

```py
out_list = []
for i in range(len(values[0])):
    out_list.append({
        keys[0]: values[0][i],
        keys[1]: values[1][i],
    })

print(out_list)
#[{'number': 1, 'type': 'bool'}, {'number': 2, 'type': 'int'}, {'number': 3, 'type': 'float'}, {'number': 4, 'type': 'double'}]
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, i was looking solution for problem with more than two keys in dict, it was an example, this solution returns only first two keys, thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) in combination with [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> keys = ['number', 'type']
>>> values = [[1, 2, 3, 4],['bool', 'int', 'float', 'double']]
>>> [{keys[0]: number, keys[1]: type} for number, type in zip(*values)]
[{'number': 1, 'type': 'bool'}, {'number': 2, 'type': 'int'}, {'number': 3, 'type': 'float'}, {'number': 4, 'type': 'double'}]
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, i was looking solution for problem with more than two keys in dict and the names of the keys is different, it was an example, this solution returns only first two keys, thank you for your help :)